# How to extract axes from R's dataEllipse function

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to extract the center coordinates, major and minor axes from R's `car:::dataEllipse` function? I'm using this function to superimpose an ellipse on an XY scatter plot.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this would be useful info to have, but for some reason it requires some extra work.

Based on the source code and the description of the `robust` argument, the center is calculated using either `MASS:::cov.trob` or `cov.wt` from the stats package:

```
tmp <- dataEllipse(Duncan$income, Duncan$education, levels=0.1*1:9, 
                   ellipse.label=0.1*1:9, lty=2, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.1)


MASS:::cov.trob(tmp[[1]])$center

#        x        y 
# 42.08207 52.91766 

stats::cov.wt(tmp[[1]])$center

#        x        y 
# 42.02314 52.81859
```

You would also need to use any `weights` if you used that in `dataEllipse`. So you can write a simple function to get all the centers from each ellipse:

```
get_centers <- function(de, robust = FALSE) {
  if (robust)
    l <- lapply(seq_along(de), function(x) MASS:::cov.trob(tmp[[x]])$center)
  else l <- lapply(seq_along(de), function(x) stats::cov.wt(tmp[[x]])$center)
  do.call('rbind', l)
}

(cent <- get_centers(tmp))

#             x        y
# [1,] 42.02314 52.81859
# [2,] 42.09468 52.93887
# [3,] 42.15538 53.04091
# [4,] 42.21279 53.13742
# [5,] 42.27070 53.23476
# [6,] 42.33239 53.33846
# [7,] 42.40228 53.45595
# [8,] 42.48882 53.60144
# [9,] 42.61681 53.81659

dataEllipse(Duncan$income, Duncan$education, levels=0.1*1:9, 
            ellipse.label=0.1*1:9, lty=2, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.1)
points(cent[1, 1], cent[1, 2], pch = 4, cex = 2)
```

[image]

It looks *slightly* off center of the point, but I have no idea why. And I'm not sure what you mean by extracting the major and minor axes.

I think it is off because `dataEllipse` returns the results of the labeled ellipses, in this example it starts at .1 and not the center ellipse, so the center point marked would be for the .1 ellipse and not the center one. But that's just a guess.